# Doctrine Symfony2 column already exists

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am working on project using Symfony2 with Doctrine and PostgreSQL as DB Engine and I have a problem. When I'm trying to do `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` after changing entities I get this error:

[image]

This is my entity class code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * LostConversation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="lost_conversation")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\LostConversationRepository")
 */
class LostConversation
{

    const MAXSREENSHOTS = 50;
    const SCREENSHOT_TIMEOUT = 10;
    const MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 30;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Room", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="room_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */

    private $room;

    /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(name="file_name ", type="string",length=40, nullable=true)
      */

    private $fileName;


    /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(name="message ", type="string",length=140, nullable=true)
      */
    private $message;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */

    private $user;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="insd", type="integer")
     */

    private $insd;
```

Thanks for every answer! :)

Comment: Check the actual state of the database. Probably you have both columns: old and new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an extra space in the column name of the `$fileName` field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="file_name ", type="string",length=40, nullable=true)
                              ^extra space here
```

Remove it and it should work.

The annotation of `$message` has the same problem.